# Master-detail UISplitviewcontroller added as one of the tabbar items - Show Master

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller, uisplitviewcontroller, master-detail

I have 5 tab bar items. Fifth item is a UISplitViewController. 
In Potrait mode, on app launch i get to see the detail screen and not the master. I am expecting the master. In landscape mode, master-detail works fine.
I add the master-detail to the splitview as below -

`ENChromecastNavigationController *master = [[ENChromecastNavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:[self p_tabbarVCFromStroyboardName:@"Main" identifier:@"ENMoreViewController" title:@"Me" imageNamed:@"icon-account"]];`

`ENChromecastNavigationController *detail = [[ENChromecastNavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:[self p_tabbarVCFromStroyboardName:@"Main" identifier:@"ENProfileViewController" title:@"Me" imageNamed:@"icon-account"]];`

`UISplitViewController *splitViewController = [[UISplitViewController alloc]init];`

`[splitViewController setViewControllers: [NSArray master,detail,nil]];`

`return splitViewController;`

Storyboard has required changes done.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Answer is available here -
http://nshipster.com/uisplitviewcontroller/

Refer section "Collapse Detail View Controller".